# How to setup topics/partitions count for EmbeddedKafka listener?

Tags: spring-kafka

I am creating integration test with embedded kafka. In the setup method I simply wait for partitions assignement:

```
    for (MessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer : kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry
            .getListenerContainers()) {
        ContainerTestUtils.waitForAssignment(messageListenerContainer,
                embeddedKafka.getEmbeddedKafka().getPartitionsPerTopic());
    }
```

This works, when I have one partition (probably there is just one listener in that case). When I assign 3 partitions, it just randomly throws an exception, that `waitForAssignement` was awaiting 1 partition to be assigned, but there are two of them. So

- Listener1 - [partition1, partition2]
- Listener2 - [partition3]

If I set manually that it needs to wait for 2 partitions, of course it will hang on the other listener. Why all partitions are not within the same listener? Maybe I am using test utils incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

That's how Kafka works.

If you have two consumers in the same group, one will get 2 partitions and the other will get 1 partition.

If you put the listeners in different groups, they will both get 3.

Comment: Consider to use a different `PartitionAssignor`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.4.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#message-listener-container. Or don't use several listeners for the same group in the same app: you can't guarantee which of the listeners is going to consume data by default.